# ASP.NET Core - prevent static file of certain filetype from being served

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, webpack, source-maps, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm attempting to configure ASP.NET Core to disallow serving .map files in certain situations. I have attempted to remove it from the known filetypes, but that doesn't seem to prevent it from actually serving the file. This is what I have now:

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "Client";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var customPort = 60001;
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer($"http://localhost:{customPort}");
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer("start");
            }
        });

        var contentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Remove(".map");
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider
        });
```

With this configuration, I am still able to load `.map` files when I browse to them. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that I was using the local development setup which proxies through Node. When this is the case, the proxy handles the static files instead of ASP.NET Core. I had to switch it up and use the published code to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UseStaticFiles` instead, before `app.UseSpa` call and even before you call `app.UseMvc` if applicable. I presume `.map` is for css/scss mappings. This is not particularly an `SPA` file, hence it is being served.

```
var contentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Remove(".map");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});

app.UseMvc(); // if applicable

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "Client";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        var customPort = 60001;
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer($"http://localhost:{customPort}");
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer("start");
    }
});

app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: With the options above, .map files are still served. They are for mapping .js files to their source file.

Comment: I see, so they are js source maps files. Before I update my answer, can I please ask if you are you going to use them in production as well?

Comment: I'm trying to create a system such that I prevent them from being loaded in production - essentially using configuration to enable or disable serving these files.